# Redirect two different users to separate pages based on their login name

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication

I would like to be able to redirect a user to a different page based on their login name. At the moment, the code below redirects all users to the same page (role.php) no matter what their login is. I have two users: student and tutor. Both of these users are redirected to role.php.
However, I would like to redirect student user to role.php and tutor user to record.php. I thought about doing a couple of if statements if member_id is 1, then redirect to role.php and if member_id is 2, then redirect to record.php. But was unable to do so.

Table structure for members table from where login credentials are checked is as follows:

member_id: 1 or 2
login: student, tutor
passwd: separate password for each user – encrypted with md5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
//Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='$login' AND passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: role.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: login-failed.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
```

EDIT: Switch statement used but now redirects to record.php for all users.I think I'm not using the switch statement correctly.

```
$login="student";
            $login="tutor";

            switch ($login)
            {
            case "student":
            header("location: role.php");   
            break;

            case "tutor":
            header("location: readonlystu.php");    
            break;
            }
```

Comment: At the moment you are setting $login to "tutor" right before using it in the switch statement.

Comment: @Moberg - I've put it inside the switch statement like so:  switch ($login)
   {
  
   $login="student";
   $login="tutor";

Comment: What shall I do, really lost now, not knowing what to do?

Comment: I think Wesley's got a working answer. Anyhow, you shouldn't set $login at all in your code. It's set when the user tries to log in, right?

Comment: @Moberg - Problem solved.I removed $login as your suggested and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for an switch statement on the role.

```
switch($iRoleId)
{
    case ROLE_STUDENT:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case ROLE_TUTOR:
        // do stuff
        break;
 }
```