# Authentication Check each time the Page reloads

Tags: php, database, authentication, laravel, reload

I have a Login which redirects you to '/admin' or '/user' depending on which role is saved in the Database. But I have the problem if someone logs in as User and gets redirected to '/user' he can type '/admin' in the URL and gets redirected there. So I guess I need a validation of the assigned role everytime the Page reloads.

Do you guys have any tips on that?

Comment: the thing you are looking for is called a 'cookie', it allows you to remember information on the current user's session. Usually web developpers use server framework that abstract that functionnality

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect two different users to separate pages based on their login name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728486/redirect-two-different-users-to-separate-pages-based-on-their-login-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to just an `auth` filter, I also have an `auth.admin` filter set up that will check to see if the user is set to an admin. If not, it will redirect to the home page: [code](https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-starter/blob/master/src/filters.php#L47)

Then add all of your admin routes into a group with the `auth.admin` filter set:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth.admin'), function()
{
    // admin routes here
}
```