# How to use authentication for users and administrators table?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, frameworks, package

I am using laravel framework.
In my config/auth.php i am using users table for customer login authentication,

I have admin panel also so how i can set the administrators table for admin login authentication?.

I need to use both users and administrators table for front and back end login.

I am using the below functions to customer login authentication,

Auth::attempt(), Auth::login(), Auth::check()

I want to use the same functions for administrators login also. How to set in laravel?

Kindly anyone help me to get over from this.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authentication with 2 different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables)

Comment: maybe this helps you [Admin Authentication Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686141/authentication-check-each-time-the-page-reloads)

Answer (score 0):

Package [Here](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth)

Not particularly used it myself as not needed to do what your doing, but seems to do what you ask.